# Heatmaps in Plotly are “stretching” data points

Tags: graph, charts, statistics, plotly, heatmap

I have a question about Heatmaps in Plotly: Why are some fields in heatmaps larger than others? 
For example here: https://plot.ly/~jonasber/1/ , all squares have different dimensions. What do I have to change in the settings so that each point in the data gets an equally sized square on the heatmap?

Also, in the example the last data point (2, 10, 3) gets displayed as (3.75, 10, 3) when you hover over the square. I experience the same in plotly.js. Is there a way to display the real data on hover?